# Visible Power Plans In Shortcut Menu

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-8, power-management

How do you choose which power plans are visible when you click on the battery in the notification area?

[image]

Comment: which version of windows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Windows 7 you gives by default (checked the Help file) Balanced and Power saving mode, to get High performance you have to manually set it to show it.

> You can create your own plan and
>   customize it to suit your needs. For
>   example, if you frequently use a
>   laptop to give presentations, you can
>   create a plan that keeps the display
>   turned on during the presentations and
>   ensures that your computer stays
>   awake.

and

> If you created power plans that you no
>   longer use or need, delete them. You
>   can't delete Balanced, Power saver,
>   High performance, or the plan that
>   you're currently using (the active
>   plan).

So in the end really the choices are fairly limited if your sticking with the Windows settings and don't hack the registry

Comment: How do I go about "hacking the registry" to change the power plans listed by default

Comment: @Midhat, I honestly wouldn't know, so I'd advise you ask it as a question, though I generally wouldn't recommend it.